# Write a jQuery selector to filter the child divs having no subclasses

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following **HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item medium type">  value1  </div>
    <div class="item">  value2  </div>
    <div class="item large">  value3  </div>
    <div class="item small">   value4  </div>
    <div class="item">  value5  </div>
    <div class="item">  value6  </div>
    <div class="item">  value7  </div>
    <div class="item medium"> value8  </div>
    <div class="item">  value9  </div>
</div>
```

**Is there a straightforward way to write a jQuery selector to get all the children of the `container` `div` which does not possess any subclasses ?**

For example, I need to write a **selector** (`$('myselector').each()`) and get only the item `div`s with values `value2`,`value5`,`value6`,`value7`,`value9` (as these `div`s don't have any subclasses).

May be I am missing the obvious. But I did a quick search to get little information on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this selector:

```
$('.container [class=item]')
```

It get every child with a class attribute exactly equal to `item` (so there is no other class).

---

But it's not really scalable, what if you need to add another class that don't exclude the element?

Maybe you should consider adding a class to other elements like:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item sub medium type">  value1  </div>
    <div class="item">  value2  </div>
    <div class="item sub large">  value3  </div>
    <div class="item sub small">   value4  </div>
    <div class="item">  value5  </div>
    <div class="item">  value6  </div>
    <div class="item">  value7  </div>
    <div class="item sub medium"> value8  </div>
    <div class="item">  value9  </div>
</div>
```

And then use `:not` in your selector:

```
$('.container .item:not(.sub)')
```

Comment: I edited my answer to remove `.item` from the selector, it was actually useless and not DRY.

Comment: If hes gonna add new classes it would be better to add class on the items he needs, like `<div class="item normal">` and then access it with `$('.normal')`

Comment: @IgorJerosimić I totally agree, but I made the assumption that he didn't want to change normal items but just to add something on others. But if it's ok to add a `normal` class on needed elements, it's definitely better!

Answer (score 1):

try [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
 $('.container .item').not('.medium , .large,.small,.type')
```

or the attribute selector

```
$('.container [class=item]').each(function(){
   //do your stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it. But, I did not want to specify the subclasses!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$("div[class$='item']")`

Also you may take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the attribute selector like this:

```
$('.container [class=item]')
```

then it will only match an element that is exactly like this:

```
<div class="item">value1</div>
```

and not this (notice the whitespace around the class name "item"):

```
<div class=" item  ">value1</div>
```

It is not safe to assume that there will never be whitespace in the class attribute. It's possible that whitespace gets inserted or left behind as the result of some jQuery DOM manipulation. A solution to this would be to trim the class attribute before selecting all elements with only the class "item".

```
$('.container')
    .children() // select all the elements contained within .container
    .each(function(){
        // strip whitespace from class attribute
        $(this).attr('class',$.trim($(this).attr('class')));
    });

// fade out all elements within .container that ONLY have the class
// "item" and nothing else
$('.container [class="item"]').fadeOut();
```